# Rails way to search column names from whole database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

Is there a convenient way in **Rails** to search specific column name from the whole database?

I've seen a few post of how it is possible in SQL syntax but none shown in Rails.
I'm using Rails4 with MySQL2 gem.

**EDIT:** More precisely, easy scenario: I want to know if a column name exists at all in database. I guess sth like an iteration over all tables and checking if the column name exists there.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want all the columns with the same name regardless of what table they are in? like `cats.name` and `users.name`. Even if its possible to do that though a huge SQL query I'm having a hard time think of any scenario where it actually would make sense to do so.

Comment: Or do you want one column for every record in the table? `SELECT foo FROM bar;`

Comment: You could just look at your db/schema.rb file

Comment: That's the most Rails-way answer so far, but I'd still like to know if there is a way for it in code :)

Comment: Why do you need to find a column name?

Comment: For debugging purposes (I have a quite big and sophisticated db), also I was just curious if it's possible in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
models = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.collect{|t| t.underscore.singularize.camelize.constantize rescue nil}
```

Then

```
columns = models.collect{|m| m.column_names rescue nil}
```

This line returns an array of all columns. You can search what ever column you like from the array.

Comment: Lovely, table names are also included.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like

```
Rails.application.eager_load! # if cache_classes is off (in dev mode is off by default)
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map{|t| t.column_names.map{|cn| t.to_s + ' - ' + cn} rescue []}.flatten.select{|el| el[/search_term/]}
```

Not the best solution ever, but it works to me